# Setting up Hadoop Multi-node Cluster on different machines using Virtual Machines

Tags: linux, hadoop, virtual-machine

I just want to know if it was possible to setup a Multi-Node Cluster on different machines, but I do not want to format these systems with CentOS or Ubuntu. I still want to keep Windows and Setup Hadoop Cluster through Virtual Machines that I installed in each machine.

Answer (score 0):

Your Virtual Machines require an OS. This could be Windows, but Hadoop will run much better on Linux, and the installation documentation assumes that you are using Linux.

As of 2021, CentOS proper was discontinued, so you may want to stick with Debian or Ubuntu.

---

Alternatively, it's possible to setup a multi-node cluster on one machine using Docker